# My Python Label text doesn't change though I am using a StringVar for the same .What's to be changed?

Tags: python, label

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def roll():
    lbl_result["text"] = str(random.randint(1, 6))

window = tk.Tk()
v = tk.StringVar()
v.set("Result")

window.columnconfigure([0,2], minsize=150)
window.rowconfigure([0, 2], minsize=50)

btn_roll = tk.Button(bg ="YELLOW",fg = "BLUE",text="Roll", command=roll)
btn_roll.grid(row =0,column =1)
lbl_result = tk.Label(width = 2,height =1,bg="GREEN",fg="YELLOW")

btn_roll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
lbl_result.grid(row=2, column=1)

a =  lbl_result.cget('text')
print(" Random no is :",a)
if a == "6":
     v.set("You Win")
lbl_result1 = tk.Label(textvariable = v,width = 6,height=2,bg="BLUE",fg="YELLOW")
lbl_result1.grid (row=1,column=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3890632)

Answer (score 0):

I incorporated the Label text change that I wanted **inside the function that's called by the command button.** Now the code works fine.

Earlier the function called was like this
def roll():
lbl_result["text"] = str(random.randint(1, 6))
NOW I changed it to
def roll():
lbl_result["text"] = str(random.randint(1, 6))

```
if lbl_result["text"] == "6":
    lbl_result1["text"] = " U Win"
```